# cognito sync manager get error when syncronize to cognito

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I want to sync some data on cognito using cognito sync manager.

Here is my implement code.

```
synchronize () {
    let template = this
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      template.dataset.synchronize({
      onSuccess: function (dataset, newRecords) {
          resolve(newRecords)
        },
      onFailure: function (err) {
          reject(err)
        },
      })
}
```

and I write a test like this

```
it('should synchronize success when #synchronize()', function () {
    this.timeout(15000)
    let cognitoSync = new CognitoSync(credentials, userAttributes.name)
    return cognitoSync.init(credentials, userAttributes.name)
    .then(function () {
      return cognitoSync.put('key123', 'value123')
    }).then(function (record) {
      return cognitoSync.synchronize()
    }).then(function (result) {
      console.log(result)
    }).catch(function (err) {
      assert.fail(err)
    })
  })
```

I log the newRecord. But there isn't any thing in the array

suppose that my credential is correct (I wrote another test to test it)

I wonder if I did anything wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Reference from here :[git hub](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-js)

Comment: Have you created any new local records in the dataset before synchronizing?

Comment: sure I did. In local I can get record details, but when I run cognitoSync.synchronize(), I got nothing in newRecords

Comment: The onSuccess() callback is triggered when a dataset is successfully downloaded from the sync store & not on uploads. Check the dataset in Cognito console & see if your records are there.